# What's the meaning of “:” in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

I'm knew to typescript/javascript but have experience with python/java/c++. Is this like the type hints in the newer versions of Python? Does ":" always mean a type hint or can it also mean something else?

Comment: It gives something a *type*. But it's also part of regular syntax, for example object literals `obj = {hello: "world"}` is an object with a `hello` property which is assigned the value `"world"`

Comment: If you are new to something  so first of all read over docs and tutorials of that topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript is a superset of ECMAScript, so first of all, the colon `:` has all the same meanings it has in ECMAScript:

- It is part of the syntax for the [*conditional operator*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-conditional-operator) `condition ? consequence1 : consequence2` which evaluates the `condition` and depending on its truthiness evaluates either `consequence1` or `consequence2` (but never both), and the value of the whole expression is the value of the consequence that was evaluated.
- It is part of the syntax for an [*object literal*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-initializer):

  ```js
  const obj = {
      foo: 4,
      "bar": 8,
      ["ba" + "z"]: 15,
  }

  console.log(obj);
  ```
- It is an [*assignment property*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-AssignmentProperty), part of the syntax for [*destructuring assignment*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-destructuring-assignment):

  ```js
  const obj = {
      foo: 16,
      bar: 23,
      baz: 42,
  }

  const { foo: frotz, baz: quux } = obj;

  console.log(frotz, quux);
  ```
- It is part of the syntax for a [*label*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-labelled-statements):

  ```js
  someLabel:
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      for (let j = 100; j < 102; j++) {
          console.log({ i, j });
          continue someLabel;
      }
  }
  ```

But it also has additional meaning in TypeScript, where it is used for *type annotations*:

```js
const i: number = 4711;
const s: string = "Hello";

function f(a: number, b: string): never
```

Note that these are not "type hints". They are type *annotations*. They aren't hinting at anything, they are strictly enforced.

Comment: This was super helpful and exactly what I was looking for. Much thanks